# How to prove $f(x) = 3 + 9x^2 + 3x^5$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z[x]$?

Tags: factoring, irreducible-polynomials

I know Eisenstein criterion won't work as the polynomial is not primitive. I don't know what other techniques I can use.

Comment: @naveendankal, please stop performing useless edits (I have rejected all of them). Just adding `$` is not proper editing. In particular, could you explain why you place `$` only around the numbers and variables in a formula, leaving everything else unformatted?

Comment: Currently not having s laptop with me and accessing this site from a prehistoric phone which is not so user friendly for detailed edits.

Answer (score 0):

$g(x)=x^5+3x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ since it is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$.
$g(x)$ has no linear factors in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ since it has no root in $\mathbb{F}_2$, and the only quadratic irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2$ is $x^2+x+1$, that is not a divisor of $g(x)$, since in $\mathbb{F}_2$
$$ x^5+x^2+1 = x^2(x^3+1)+1 = x^2(x+1)(x^2+x+1)+1.$$

Comment: I made a mistake by assuming it was irreducible over Z[x]. It is not irreducible over Z[x] as it factors into 3(x^5+3x^2+1), (where 3 is irreducible in Z[x] but not over Q[x]. But thanks anyway for the proof of g(x) = x^5 + 3x^2 + 1 being irreducible over Q[x]. Using Gauss lemma it makes it irreducible over Z[x] as g(x) is primitive.